# automysqlbackup on cPanel server not ignoring eximstats

Tags: mysql

I am backing up my cPanel server databases with automysqlbackup, in /etc/automysqlbackup.conf I have set: `CONFIG_db_exclude=( 'information_schema' 'cphulkd' 'eximstats' 'leechprotect' 'mysql' 'modsec' )`

But I am getting the following errors:

```
###### WARNING ######
Errors reported during AutoMySQLBackup execution.. Backup failed
Error log below..
mysqldump: Got error: 145: Table './eximstats/smtp' is marked as crashed and should be repaired when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `Email-List`': SHOW VIEW command denied to user 'automysqlbackup'@'localhost' for table 'Email-List' (1142)
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `object_1`': SHOW VIEW command denied to user 'automysqlbackup'@'localhost' for table 'object_1' (1142)
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `object_1`': SHOW VIEW command denied to user 'automysqlbackup'@'localhost' for table 'object_1' (1142)
du: WARNING: use --si, not -H; the meaning of the -H option will soon
change to be the same as that of --dereference-args (-D)
```

My questions are:

1. Any ideas why eximstats is not being ignored?
2. Given I am a non root user (account created with `mysql > grant select, lock tables on *.* to 'automysqlbackup'@'localhost' identified by 'password';`) how can the other errors be resolved?

Comment: To the down voter - Instead of blindly down voting perhaps you could be more constructive and advise/comment how I could improve my question and help add value to the community

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quite similar error and I finally left the default mysql user for `automysqlbackup` that was for me `debian-sys-maint` (from `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`)

This one had already the proper rights set.